# Symfony form, EntytyType/ChoiceType from 2 different entities

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I need to create a dropdown in a Symfony form that contains entities from 2 different tables, for example:

[image]

Where EntityA and EntityB are two different classes and MySQL tables, with a different structure.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: I guess by creating an entity that refers to a MySQL view would be a solution... other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `choice_loader` option of a `ChoiceType` field.

You can use a `CallbackChoiceLoader` to load your entities through a closure or implement your own choice loader as a service that you can inject to your form type.

This allows you to build a custom query (or execute two queries in this case) and return the choice list built from the results lazily.

Check the official documentation here (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-loader).